# Extending recursive Typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsonschema

I'm using the TS type for JSON Schema: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/json-schema/index.d.ts

Short version:

```
interface JSONSchema4 {
  properties?: {
    [k: string]: JSONSchema4;
  } | undefined;
}
```

This type is recursive. I'd like to extend this type with custom properties. E.g. currently, something like this doesn't match the type:

```
{ instanceof: 'Date' }
```

I'd like to add `instanceof?: string` as a field to `JSONSchema4`. Is this possible?

Comment: `instanceof` is a reserved word, you might be able to get away with putting it in quotes though... `'instanceof': ...`

Comment: But how would I extend a recursive type?

Comment: I think you have to extend the interface and replace all properties in the interface that can be of type `JSONSchema4` to refer to your own interface type. It's not pretty but it's the only thing I can come up with

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NBPLbW) meet your needs?  If so, I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example to show a failing use case.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, interfaces are open, unlike types that are closed. So, you can add your keyword simply by declaring an interface with the same name that contains your keyword. That interface effectively extends the original type.

```js
interface JSONSchema4 {
  instanceof?: string;
}
```